# Decrement value from SQL database bug

Tags: c#

I have 2 asp.net WebForms, WebForm1 contains a button that redirects into WebForm2 which contains a contact form that needs to be filled to proceed order. I have a drop-down list in it that is connected to the database, and depending on which product a button on the WebForm1 is clicked, the current quantity is displayed from the specific product from the database. After the ordering, no matter what quantity is selected from the drop-down list, it always decrements the quantity in the database by 1. Can anyone see my code and tell me where is my mistake? I tried many different approaches and methods but every time is the same, it only deducts the quantity by 1.

How to make a deduction in the database by the same value that is selected from the drop-down list?

Here is my code:

```
C#:
string productName = Request.QueryString["productname"];
        txt_product13.Text = productName;
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            {"@ProductName", productName }
        };
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters(dictionary);
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            int val = Convert.ToInt32(dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Text);
            connection.Open();
            var sql = "UPDATE ProductsDB SET Quantity = Quantity - " + val + " WHERE ProductName = @ProductName";
            connection.Execute(sql, parameters);
            connection.Close();
        }
```

In case it matters, upper in the code I have the same approach for getting the currency, and getting the quantity from a specific product in a drop-down list starting from 1 to its max quantity:

C#:
string productName = Request.QueryString["productname"];
txt_product13.Text = productName;

```
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
{ "@ProductName", productName }
      };

    var parameters = new DynamicParameters(dictionary);
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM ProductsDB WHERE ProductName = @ProductName";
        var product = connection.QuerySingle<Product>(sql, parameters);
        CultureInfo EuroCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
        txt_productprice.Text = product.Price.ToString("c", EuroCulture);

        for (int i = 1; i <= product.Quantity; i++)
        {
            dropdownlist1.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
        }
```

Comment: (Probably unrelated, but:) 1. Never trust user input. Validate it and don't even expect it to be a valid integer. 2. Do not concat SQL statements. Use Sql Parameters.

Comment: Try `int val = Convert.ToInt32(dropdownlist1.SelectedItem.Value);` maybe?